# Hissing/Buzzing sound in headphone - Asus X200MA Laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, audio, noise

I have Asus X200MA Laptop with Windows 8.1 64 bit.
Whenever I plug in headphones into the combo socket, I hear constant hissing or buzzing sound in the headphones. It slightly varies in intensity as I load more applications like Explorer but it's constant.

I have tried with 3 different headphones but it's constant.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the latest Realtek drivers from Asus website but that did not help.

It comes regardless if the laptop is on battery on AC power.

I have now run out of ideas and suspect it to be hardware issue. If there are any further pointers towards troubleshooting, would be glad to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) from a live USB Stick (or a DVD). You don't need to install a Linux system, just start it once from the stick and select "try" instead of "install". Wait, until the sytem has started. Then plug in your headphones, and start any audio application, e.g. the sample audio files in the music folder. If the issue consists, it's a hardware issue. If not, it is something related to Windows.

**If you don't know how to create and boot a live Linux USB Stick for tryout:**
Use https://unetbootin.github.io/. Download the application to your Windows system and run it. Find an USB stick with at least 4GB, and be sure to empty it before proceeding, since it will be completely overwritten. Select your Stick in Unetbootin and a distribution, like Ubuntu. Then wait for the download and copy to the stick to finish, and restart your computer. You need to select the stick as a boot medium, so hit keys like <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> or similiar immediately after turning on your computer. Refer to your computers' manual, or to one of the many tutorials available online, if you're stuck. This official tutorial explains it as well: [Try Ubuntu tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0)

This will allow you to diagnose if the issue is hardware- or Windows-related.

Comment: The issue remained even with Live Linux. However spraying IPA cleaner into the socket has partially done something and now the buzz comes only in Right side and left audio is somewhat depressed. The stereo is now out of balance after spraying IPA cleaner. Also if I just slightly unplug the 3 pin jack and in a way keep it in something like mono position (probably since R is disconnected and L seems to have shorted internally ) then clear but mono audio comes in both sides.

Comment: @rajeev Then it’s clearly a hardware issue - Good luck in fixing your headphone jack! Maybe spray some cleaner on cotton buts and use them to clean the headphone jack?